# Parshas Shekalim before Adar I

Tags: halacha, mistakes, torah-reading, four-parshiot, adar

Suppose a Shul makes a mistake one week, forgetting there are 2 Adars that year, and the Baal Korei reads Parshas Shekalim. Would they read Parshas Shekalim again before Rosh Chodesh Adar Sheni?

Comment: I see to recall if all 4 are read in the wrong month, you're ok with Shekalim and Zachor but need to repeat Para and Hachodesh as they have to be read after Purim.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The printed version of Tur ([end of Orach Chaim 688](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14268&pgnum=614)) says that in that case the parshiyos would not have to be read again, and Beis Yosef there agrees. However, Darchei Moshe and Bach there argue that this version is incorrect, and that indeed they would have to be reread in (or, for Shekalim, before) Adar Sheni.

Comment: see also Nitei Gavriel Purim 17:2 - http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46446&pgnum=135